# Subversion server connection problems

Tags: windows, svn, connection

I have just set up Subversion server, and test repository, on a Windows server. However I can't connect to it from any computers. Using TortoiseSVN, I get the error message:

> Error: Can't connect to host '[host]': A connection attempt failed because the
>   Error: connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   Error: connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I can connect to another SVN repository on a different server, so it's surely a problem with this server and installation.

- The Subversion service is running and listening on port 3690.
- I can ping the server's IP address just fine from various PCs.
- Firewall is disabled on the server and my PC (and nothing is blocked by the router).

Any ideas why I might not be able to connect?

**Update**: More info as requested by AlberT:

- `netstat -a` lists, among other lines, `TCP    GOWANPOINT:3690        GOWANPOINT:0           LISTENING`
- I'm using TortoiseSVN to connect, as noted above. I'm trying to check out the new repository I created, and connecting to: `svn://[server-ip]:3690/project_name`
- Tried telnet-ing (using putty) and got a similar timeout error.
- OS: Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a firewall between the client and the server which doesn't allow to use the SVN port.

To verify this, try to run the subversion server on port 80 (you can use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) to create a temporary reroute).

You can also use `telnet <host> <port>` to check that you can connect. In this case, you must see the connection on the server with `netstat`. If that doesn't work, there is definitely a firewall somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide some additional informations, such as:

- **netstat** output on the server, making clear on which port of which interface the server is listening on
- the **svn command line you are using**, so that we can exclude any typo and verify the port, protocol and path you are trying to use
- try to **telnet to the server on svn port** and tell us if the connection success. Possibly C&P the output
- the **OS of the server**
- try to exclude DNS problems using the **server IP**, not the name

Comment: OK, question updated.

Comment: Ok, if telnet times out too I'd try a tracert or, better, a tcptracert in order to see where your packets are deaded. You can use level four traceroute (http://pwhois.org/lft/ ) for example. In order to see if your PC can effectively reach via TCP connections the server try to telnet to the server-ip on a different port you know has a service enabled, or run a server through netcat -l to accomplish this task.
What is the net topology between your PC and the server?

Comment: `tracert [ip]:3690` simply returns "Unable to resolve target system name [ip]:3690". I don't see any options about port numbers, was that correct usage?

Comment: as I said you have to use a TCP tracing program, *not* the MS bundled tracert as it uses ICMP packets and you can't in any way probe tcp ports as you need

Answer (score 0):

That looks like as if the Subversion server is not running. I've done that quite a few times myself. I've done this so much, that I created a page for me to look it up. I use the custom svnserve.exe server. If this is what you're using then look at the URL below for how to turn it into a Windows Service.

http://systemwidgets.com/Support/SubversionArticles/RunningsvnserveasaWindowsService/tabid/84/Default.aspx?PageContentMode=1

I've settled on the [CollabNet binaries](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/), as they have a nice install package for both the svnserve and Apache editions of the server.

Comment: I'm sure the service is running. Under Services is "CollabNet Subversion svnserve", which is Running, with the path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet Subversion Server\svnserve.exe" --service -r "c:\svn_repository" --listen-port "3690"`

Comment: That command-line tells me that you are running Windows 2003 x64. What is the Subversion version? I had problems with 1.4 with x64 OS. Subversion 1.5 fixed the issues I had.

Also you don't need --listen-port "3690", as that is svnserve's default port.

Comment: IMHO if the server was not listening on the port and you *can* reach the server and there is no fw in the middle as reported then the client has not to hang, but an ICMP message should be received in a few ms.

Comment: I'm using Subversion 1.6.5, using the CollabNet binaries. And the "--listen-port" thing is added by svn by default.